# CS:GO does not run on 18.04

Tags: 18.04, games, steam

I launch Steam, select `Counter-Strike: Global Offensive`, click "Play", black screen appears for a few seconds, then it closes. That's it.

I tried another Steam game and that seems to work fine.

How do I fix this and actually be able to play a good native Linux game instead of rebooting to Windows?

By the way, I played CS:GO on a previous Ubuntu version before. It was either 14.04 or 16.04, I can't quite remember. But it's not working in 18.04.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem was solved by using `-nojoy` in launch options.

Answer (score 1):

Try to verify integrity of game files in the properties of CS:GO.

[image]

Otherwise try to re-install it.

Comment: It says, "1 file failed to validate and will be reacquired". And it then downloads a small amount, maybe that 1 failed file. But the game still fails to launch and after the crash, the same error shows again when validating files integrity.

Comment: I think I already reinstalled it once without any success.